# a small accident in.htaccess syntax >_<

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Internal Server Error. .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /path-to-new-location/? [L,R=301]
Redirect URLs with query parameters (files placed in subdirectory)
```

I tried redirect:
http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1
to:

http://www.example.com/path-to-new-location/

Was found solution by myself:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?g=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%4\? [R,L]
```

Comment: Remove last line that starts with `Redirect URLs...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /path-to-new-location/ [L,R=301]
# Redirect URLs with query parameters (files placed in subdirectory)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was found a problem and edit question >_< can you  answer please?

Comment: You should NEVER change your question after you get an answer. SO is a reference for EVERY programmer, it's not just a convenient method for you to get help.